# Redirect to new page with argument value

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on wordpress and would like to implement redirecting in a way that if someone wants to visit the url with any id:

```
http://www.example.com/123456789
```

will be redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?id=123456789
```

Any idea how can i achieve this? I believe I have to use .htaccess file but any help will be highly appreciated..

**EDIT** Standard Rules I have within .htaccess are

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Can't do it without taking into account the WP rule set. Is it the standard one?

Comment: I am new to wordpress, what is standard rule?

Comment: Check the .htaccess file at WP install directory and copy+paste it's content into the question. If it is a new install, the block of rules should be the standard one but it is better to be sure.

Comment: Oh yes, .htaccess is standard, please see its content in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try replacing the rule-set in your question with the following:

```
# BEGIN Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}    !/document         [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]

# Add these lines
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !search\.php         [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /document/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /wordpress/search.php?id=%1      [L,NC]

</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

The last rule maps silently:

`http://localhost/wordpress/document/123`

To:

`http://localhost/wordpress/search.php?id=123`

where `123` is a dynamic string.

For permanent redirection, replace the last [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC].

Comment: Just forgot to mention, this id is dynamic, it could be any id, whatever the id is, it should be redirected to search.php with the given id as url parameter.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. I can modify the answer to exclude from the WP rule-set all requests that are not to `/wordpress/`. Would be that okay? Maybe you have another idea to identify the requests that you want to exclude from the WP rules, though. There has to be a pattern.

Comment: can we not use something like `$` to represent any id?

Comment: Is there anything that identifies the requests to `search.php` from others NOT to Wordpress?

Comment: No I don't think so.. I created a page `search.php` within wordpress directory where i will put the script to search for the documents with the given id.. I was trying something like `RewriteRule ^$1 ^search.php?url=$1` where base is `/wordpress/`?

Comment: okay lets suppose I use this: `http://www.example.com/document/123`. What rules would I need for this and how can I redirect this to `http://www.example.com/search.php?id=123`?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I am on my local machine, does it matter? it say page not found

Comment: According to your last comment, both `/document` and `search.php` are at ROOT directory. Are they? If so, yes, the URL structure might be different, please post the complete testing URL used at localhost.

Comment: I only have search.php in the root of wordpress installation. The url I am trying is `http://localhost/wordpress/document/123` and my search script is at the location `http://localhost/wordpress/search.php`

Comment: I am just trying to achieve short urls for my documents. So I can use the url such as `http://localhost/wordpress/document/123` to display this document

Comment: Yes. That's the idea. Modified my answer.

Comment: Exellent. Works now :) Thanks alot

Comment: Just another quick question. Is it possible to make it even shorter by removing the /document part? By just using `http://localhost/wordpress/123`?

Comment: No. Will have the same problem. There is no way to know if `123` is for WP or for search as it is a dynamic string that can be anything.

Comment: Ok no worries.. This will do good too.. Cheers mate :D

Comment: In my experience, it doesn't modify it. It creates a new rule-set in the current .htaccess file, if any, when it doesn't exist. But, keep a back up just in case.